# Use series to get at value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series and dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series(['x', 'y', 'z'], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3), s.index, s.values)
```

I want to use `s` to select elements of `df`.  I want a series of:

```
[df.loc['a', 'x'], df.loc['b', 'y'], df.loc['c', 'z']]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
df.lookup(s.index, s.values)

[0 4 8]
```

Or as a pandas.Series:

```
pd.Series(df.lookup(s.index, s.values), s.index)

a    0
b    4
c    8
```

**Timings**

Using larger data than what's in the question:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase

s = pd.Series(list(ascii_lowercase), list(ascii_uppercase))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(26**2).reshape(26, 26), s.index, s.values)
```

Yields the following timings:

```
%timeit pd.Series(df.lookup(s.index, s.values), s.index)
1000 loops, best of 3: 241 μs per loop

%timeit pd.Series([df.at[i, s[i]] for i in s.index], s.index)
1000 loops, best of 3: 770 μs per loop

%timeit pd.Series([df.ix[ind,col] for ind, col in s.iteritems()], s.index)
1000 loops, best of 3: 381 μs per loop
```

Comment: It's like an abandoned method though. I remember seeing it in one of Wes's answers but docs seem to be old.

Comment: I should've tested bigger data.  Can't +1 again though.

Answer (score 2):

Use `at` in a `list` comprehension.

```
pd.Series([df.at[i, s[i]] for i in s.index], s.index)

a    0
b    4
c    8
dtype: int64
```

---

#### Timing

**I'm leaving this here, but this is insufficient as pointed out by @root**

**Just list/array**

[image]

**Build series**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just chiming in

```
In [295]: %timeit pd.Series([df.at[i, s[i]] for i in s.index], s.index)
10000 loops, best of 3: 96.5 µs per loop

In [296]: %timeit pd.Series([ df.ix[ind,col] for ind, col in s.iteritems()  ], s.index)
10000 loops, best of 3: 86.3 µs per loop
```